# Python : search two regular expression in one command

Tags: python

How do I search for two regular expressions in one `findall` command? I have an ugly program to get this done, but would like to learn a better Python way to do this.

In the following example, I would like to identify all the servers with either (alarm1 side0 & alarm1 side1) OR (problem 2).

File :

```
Server 1, side 0, Alarm 1
Server 1, side 1, Alarm 1
Server 1, Problem 2
Server 2, Alarm 2
Server 3, side 0, Alarm 1
Server 4, side 1, Alarm 1
Server 5, Alarm 3
```

Expected output :

```
Server 1, Alarm 1, Alarm 2
Server 2, Alarm 2
```

---

Script :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
import os

def main():
  server_alarm_list=[]
  with open('sample_data') as f:
    text=f.read()
    Alarm1_side0_tuple=re.findall(r'Server (\d+), side 0, Alarm 1', text)
    Alarm1_side1_tuple=re.findall(r'Server (\d+), side 1, Alarm 1', text)
    Alarm2_tuple=re.findall(r'Server (\d+), Problem 2', text)
    for i in Alarm1_side0_tuple:
      if i in Alarm1_side1_tuple:
        server_alarm_list.append(i)
     for i in Alarm2_tuple:
       if i in server_alarm_list:
         print "Server" + i + ", Alarm 1, Alarm 2"
       else:
         print "Server" + i + ", Alarm2"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can't search two patterns with `findall`, but your pattern can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), which sounds like what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what I was doing incorrectly, but alternation (didnt know it was called that) worked when i retried it.